# hiding tabs from bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have this 3 tabs defined in my html. I am using tabs from bootstrap.css

```
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" style="margin-top: 26px;">
                    <li><a href="#product" data-toggle="tab" >Product</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#version" data-toggle="tab">Version</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#language" data-toggle="tab">Language</a></li>

   </ul>
```

I am trying to hide tabs on one of click event of button. I can get only last tab to hide like this below

```
$('#myTab a:last').hide();
```

But i also want to hide second tab called Version but cant hide it. I tried below code

```
$('#myTab a:second').hide();
```

But doesn't work and gives error as "Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: second "

How should i go about this? I cant find much information on this link [here](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tabs)

Answer (score 1):

Would this not do the job for you?

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" style="margin-top: 26px;">
    <li><a href="#product" data-toggle="tab" >Product</a></li>
    <li class="hideme"><a href="#version" data-toggle="tab">Version</a></li>
    <li class="hideme"><a href="#language" data-toggle="tab">Language</a></li>
</ul>

.hideme {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: then how can i unhide it again. Is my solution which i posted is also ok?

Comment: @AshReva- Why/When do you want to hide the tabs?

Comment: I want to hide based on certain requirement from my manager. For instance when click inside the content of product tab i want to show version and language tab and hide product tab. On my breadcrumb when i click i want to show only product tab and hide remaining

Answer (score 1):

I think i managed to do it by knockout way. Defined tabs as below and binded with observable. see below

```
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" style="margin-top: 26px;">
                    <li><a href="#product" data-toggle="tab" >Product</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#version" data-toggle="tab"  data-bind ="visible: showVersionTab">Version</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#language" data-toggle="tab" data-bind ="visible: showLanguageTab">Language</a></li>

  </ul>
```

Then i just set observables to true and false whenever i need it.

Answer (score 1):

Why not assign id's to your `<li>` elements? 
eg.

```
<li id='1'><a href="#product" data-toggle="tab" >Product</a></li>
<li id='2'><a href="#version" data-toggle="tab">Version</a></li>
<li id='3'><a href="#language" data-toggle="tab">Language</a></li>
```

Then you can hide:

```
$('#1').hide();
```

and 'un'-hide

```
$('#1').show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this         `$('#myTab li:eq(1) a').tab('show');`

```
            $('#myTab a[href="#profile"]').tab('show'); // Select tab by name`
```

Comment: nope doesnt work. I had too tried this earlier but gives error like "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'hide' "

Comment: didnt understood what you mean? What javascript code you wish to see. I am just calling the code which i mentioned in my question inside click event to button. I can hide last tab but cant hide second tab

Comment: I also tried your second option but doesnt work. same error. Please help.

Comment: create a jsfiddle or a test page of wat u r trying

Comment: How about just putting a class on each each tab you want to hide and and setting display:none in your css for that class?

Answer (score 0):

To hide it, it is sufficient to remove the active class from the content.

In the element to the attribute href has the id of the element "content" so if we use jquery we can do the following:

```
var contentId = $('#myTab a:last').prop('hash'); // href value.
$( contentId ).removeClass('active');
```

to search by index you can use:

```
$('#myTab li:eq(2) a').prop('hash');
$( contentId ).removeClass('active');
```